# Proof of Incompleteness - Existence of Gödel number $g$

Tags: incompleteness

I was watching a video: https://youtu.be/HeQX2HjkcNo?t=1171
and had a quesion on the incompleteness proof.

In the video, he introduces us to the statement: "There is no proof for the statement with Godel number $g$"

Then he says that the trick is that the Godel number of that statement is $g$. My question is how can you be sure that such a number $g$ exists? Since the conjecture itself has $g$ in it, wouldn't the Godel number be dependent on $g$? More specifically, I believe that the Godel number of any statement that has a number $x$ is greater than $x$. Is that not always the case?

Comment: A statement that explicitly contains the numeral for $x$  (e.g. $SS\dots  SS0$ with $x$ occurrences of the "successor" symbol $S$) will indeed have Gödel number bigger than $x$. But a statement can contain a description of how to compute $x$, and then its Gödel number can be much smaller. Part of Gödel's discovery was a method for producing a statement that contains a description of how to compute its own Gödel number.

Comment: Ah, thank you!! That is interesting

Comment: I believe this is fundamentally a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178598/question-about-goedels-incompleteness-proof). That said, this *is* a very good and natural question to have about the incompleteness theorem, and I don't know why it got downvoted.

Comment: See also [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83155/can-we-find-strong-fixed-points-in-the-fixed-point-lemma-of-g%C3%B6dels-incompletene), about pathological Godel numbering mechanisms which **do** allow literally-the-same fixed points!